# Searching an Array for an Exact Match in Python

Tags: python

I was wondering how I can make an array search for an exact match and if the city isn't found it should output "Not a city in michigan."

Code should out put: 
Chicago
Brooklyn
Watervliet
Acme

```
citiesInMichigan = ["Acme", "Albion", "Detroit", "Watervliet", "Coloma", "Saginaw", "Richland", "Glenn", "Midland", "Brooklyn"] 

# Get user input
inCity = input("Enter name of city: ")


# Write your test statement here to see if there is a match.
if inCity == citiesInMichigan:
    print("City Found")
# If the city is found, print "City found."

# Otherwise, "Not a city in Michigan" message should be printed.
```

Comment: `if inCity in citiesInMichigan:`

Comment: Hi there, you are asking about how basic operators in Python work. An introductory Python tutorial like [this one](https://python.swaroopch.com/op_exp.html) can be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the in statement.

```
if inCity in citiesInMichigan:
    print("City Found")
else:
    print("Not a city in michigan.")
```

Pay attention that the in statement is an exact match. This means that you may need to trim and lower/upper case your input.